# MYSQL - UPDATE multiple fields based on single CASE statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, case

**OBJECTIVE**

I am looking for a way to update one or both fields using the same CASE statement

```
UPDATE vendor
    SET special_cost =
    (
        CASE
            WHEN
                cost > 14
            THEN
                14
            ELSE
                SET special_cost = cost, cost = 14
        END
    )    
WHERE upc = '12345678912345'
```

**LOGIC**

This is some logic that explains what I want to happen above.

```
if ($cost > 14) {
    $special_cost = 14;
} else {
    $special_cost = $cost;
    $cost = 14;
}
```

It does not seem that there is a way to do this with a single CASE statement. Perhaps, this can be done with the mysql IF statement?

Comment: What is the logic supposed to be doing?  It doesn't make sense to me.  Sample data and desired results help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I updated the question to reflect the intended logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to `case` *expressions* not `case` *statements*.

You appear to want something like this:

```
UPDATE vendor
    SET special_cost = GREATEST(cost, 14),
        cost = 14
    WHERE upc = '12345678912345';
```